# Dropbox Syncing Issue with android application

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I follow the steps provided at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android  for the synchronization of my android application with Dropbox. On pressing the Linktodropbox Button it the app navigates me to sign in page of dropbox. when i enter my credentials it gives me an error

ERROR:  "This app cannot be used with the Sync Api"

I changed the App_key and App_password with my app's key and app's passwords provided to me by dropbox. Can anybody me in this regard. thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, i just restarted my app and it worked all good

Answer (score 2):

This most likely means you're trying to use an app with Full Dropbox permission. The Sync API only supports App folder and File type permissions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Maybe you can tell us what kind of app you created and show us the code you tried to run?

Comment: the application is actually similar to a text editor, all i need to do is to export and import my data from dropbox.

Comment: When I said "what kind of app you created" I mean what options you chose when you created the app on the Dropbox website. (Drop-ins? Dropbox API? Existing files? File type permissions?)

Comment: Okay, we'll go one question at all. Next one is "Files and datastores" or "Datastores only."

Comment: That sounds right... I'd say you should open a support ticket (click "API support" at https://www.dropbox.com/developers) so we can look at your exact app key/secret.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem, but I go to Google Play, download Dropbox and install it to device then I can login to dropbox by my app

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error you must to do the right choice. Go https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create. When you register your dropbox application at the step 4 ("What type of files does your app need access to?") select the "Specific file types" and your issue resolves. For more questions to create apps Android studio based write me. Thanks.